# Use multiple supervisord program threads for seperate APScheduler tasks or one program with one scheduler for many tasks?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, supervisord, apscheduler

I'm developing a flask web application that requires a few tasks to be scheduled for the night time and was curious to pick some of your minds.

From the perspective of efficiency and performance of the application itself, would it be better to set up multiple supervisor program threads to each run a specific blocking APScheduler (at different times but same time frame), or to call all tasks back to back in 1 supervisor program thread with 1 blocking scheduler?

Thank you!